# Obtener cantidad de valores más altos de la media

Tags: c

Ayuda para poder resolver este problema:

> Calcule las medias de las estaturas de una clase. Deducir cuántos son más altos que la media y cuántos más bajos que dicha media.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    float estatura;
    float suma;
    int total;
    int x;
    printf("Ingresa el total de personas\n");
    scanf("%i",&total);
    x = 1;
    suma = 0;
    while (x<=total) {
        printf("Ingresa la estatura\n");
        scanf("%f",&estatura);
        suma = suma+estatura;
        x = x+1;
    }
    printf("La estatura promedio de todo el grupo es: %f\n",suma/total);
    printf("Los mas altos de la media son: %i\n",total);
    printf("Los mas bajos de la media son: %i\n",total);
}
```

Es lo que llevo pero no se como sacar el numero de altos y numero de bajos referente a la media.

Comment: Hola, por ahora tu código esta bien pero para hacer lo de la media supongo que tengas que almacenar las estaturas en un array, luego comprobar elemento por elemento si es mas alto que la media.

Comment: Como consejo, no hagas la comparación mientras pides la estatura. Primero, como dijo Aaron, guarda los datos en un array, y ya luego procede a hacer las operaciones que necesites sobre este array. Es decir, separa el problema en pequeños problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver el problema he usado 2 bucles `for`.

Si no estás familiarizado con ellos ahora te explico como he resuelto el problema.

Lo primero y más importante, **crear el array donde se almacenan las estaturas introducidas**. Este array de tipo `float`, lo necesitamos para poder almacenar estaturas con decimales.

El tamaño del array es igual que el numero de estaturas que se va a introducir, lo cual simplifica bastante el problema.

Luego haces un bucle `for` para almacenar las estaturas en diferentes elementos del array a la vez que las vas sumando para luego ahorrar trabajo y no tener que hacer otro bucle solo para sumar las estaturas.

Lo siguiente es calcular el **promedio**. Para ello utilizamos la variable tamaño que has solicitado, en otro caso también podrías utilizar `sizeof` para sacar el numero de elementos del array.

Lo siguiente es hacer otro bucle `for`, para comparar cada estatura del array con el promedio.

Si esta estatura es **mayor** que el promedio, hacemos un incremento en el contador de mayores. En caso de que la estatura sea **menor o igual** que el promedio, incrementamos el contador de menores.

Te dejo el código a continuación:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float promedio= 0,suma = 0;
    int total = 0, mayores = 0, menores = 0;
    printf("Ingresa el total de personas\n");
    scanf("%i",&total);
    float numero[total];
    
    for(int i = 0; i <total; i++){
        printf("Ingrese la estatura: ");
        scanf("%f", &numero[i]);
        suma = suma + numero[i];
    }
    
    promedio = (suma / total);
    
    for(int x = 0; x<total; x++){
        if(numero[x] > promedio){
            mayores ++;
        }
        else{
            menores ++;
        }
    }
    printf("El promedio es %f, de las estaturas introducidas %d son mayores que el promedio y %d son menores que el promedio",promedio,mayores,menores);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que el código solo es válido en compiladores que soportan [VLA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays). De lo contrario el tamaño del arreglo debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación.

Answer (score 0):

Mi aproximación fue tomando los hints que te dí en los comentarios. Es decir, cree una función para cada cosa para dividir el problema, y luego llamarlas en el main.

Al final genera un reporte de tipo *HeightsReport*:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int get_total_people() {
    int total;
    printf("Ingresa el total de personas: ");
    scanf("%i", &total);
    return total;
}

float* create_heights_array(int total) {
    float* sizes_array = malloc(total * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("Ingresa la estatura %i: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &sizes_array[i]);
    }
    return sizes_array;
}

float calculate_mean(float* sizes_array, int total) {
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i < total; i++)
        sum+=sizes_array[i];
    return sum/total;
}

typedef struct HeightsReport {
    int below_avg;
    int above_avg;
    float mean;
} HeightsReport;

HeightsReport create_height_report(float* estaturas, int total) {
    HeightsReport report;

    report.below_avg = 0;
    report.above_avg = 0;
    report.mean = calculate_mean(estaturas, total);

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        if (estaturas[i] < report.mean)
            report.below_avg++;
        else if (estaturas[i] > report.mean)
            report.above_avg++;
    }

    return report;
}

int main() {

    int total = get_total_people();
    float* estaturas = create_heights_array(total);
    HeightsReport report = create_height_report(estaturas, total);

    printf("Promedio de estaturas: %f\n", report.mean);
    printf("Cantidad de mas altos de la media: %i\n", report.above_avg);
    printf("Cantidad de mas bajos de la media: %i\n", report.below_avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Ya cuando lo corres, obtienes esto:

```
$ gcc -o estaturas estaturas.c && ./estaturas
Ingresa el total de personas: 5
Ingresa la estatura 1: 12
Ingresa la estatura 2: 20
Ingresa la estatura 3: 30
Ingresa la estatura 4: 40
Ingresa la estatura 5: 50
Promedio de estaturas: 30.000000
Cantidad de mas altos de la media: 2
Cantidad de mas bajos de la media: 2
```

Donde no contó la estatura que es igual a la de la media, ya que específicaste sólo o más bajos o más altos, pero no iguales.